# Who hechshers P'til Tekhelet?

Tags: tzitzis, hechsher-certification, techeles

P'til Tekhelet is an organisation which makes M. trunculus techeilet. Who hechshers their tzitziot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://tekhelet.com/tekhelet/ask-ptil-tekhelet/

> Q. Who is the mashgiach on the process making sure it's lishma, etc.? Who gives the official hechsher?
>
> A. **R. Eliyahu Tavger is the Rav of the Amuta.** The workers doing the dyeing, spinning, twining of the threads are all yirei shamayim Jews who are very careful to state explicitly before every process, “L’shem mitzvat tzitzit.”

Comment: Just for the record, they also dye niputz lishmah tzitzit, which are not made in-house. I can't remember which company supplies them with niputz lishmah strings.